# Table column filled later on

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm new on Laravel and as I'm playing around with it I encounter this issue.
I have a registration system which worked fine but now I wanted to add a new field in my table (description field for users).
However, this description field, I don't want to be filled when the user signs up, I want the user to fill this when he gets on his profile and updates a modal window.

The problem is, if I let that filed empty, I get an error when I sign up saying that the description filed can't be empty.

This is what I use in my UserController in order to update the description field but I'm not sure if is correct.

```
public function postDesc(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
    'description' => 'required|min:20'
  ]);
  $user = User::all();
  $user->description = $request->input('description');
  $user->save();
  return redirect()->route('user.profile.edit');
}
```

This is how I opened the form:
`{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PUT', 'action' => 'UserController@postDesc', 'class' => 'profile-form']) !!`}

Comment: Remove   $this->validate($request, [
    'description' => 'required|min:20'
  ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `required` validation rule, that's why you get the message. You should use different validation rules for register page and profile update form.

Good practice is to [create two Request classes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) and use them for validation of two forms.

Comment: Ok, I just learned about that, thanks. I set up two Request classes one to register the user and another one to store the description. However I'm still getting the 'description' doesn't have a default value, after I sign up..

Comment: @OvidiuG this is DB related error. You should add `->nullable()` or `->default('No description')` to `description` column definition in migration file.

Comment: yes, I just figured that out. Now it works. I just have to figure how to update the 'description' field now because the above method I wrote it's not working.

Comment: I was finally able to get this done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I will prefer to keep your description column `nullalbe()`. So it won't throw an error that description field is empty at the time of sign up.

And later you can update the description field.

```
public function postDesc(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'description' => 'required|min:20'
    ]);

    // Get the logged in user id using auth and then updating description filed
    $user = User::where('user_id',  Auth::id())
               ->update([
               'description' => $request->description
               ]);

    return redirect()->route('user.profile.edit');
}
```